# In Power BI, using DAX. How do I get multiple (text) values/strings from a slicer?

Tags: powerbi, dax, slicers

For a multi page report I'd like to put all synchronised slicers on the first page and then show the selection result on cards in all aother pages.

I followed this tutorial by Curbal:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_k_Qxb6pyCc

This works for selecting numbers. But....

I have text in the selectable fields.
So how do I return multiple selected strings from a slicer?
I hope it's just a small thing that I'm missing.
[edit]
Here's two images:
[First page with slicers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAZLD.png)
[Second page with visuals and cards based on the selection on page one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvzyR.png)

Kind regards,

Erik Crins

Comment: Can you show image of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function that aggregates the values in a table - `CONCATENATEX`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/concatenatex-function-dax

If you want to show all the values selected in a slicer on a card you can use it like this:

```
Text = CONCATENATEX(ALLSELECTED(Slicer[Field]), [Field], ", ")
```

Comment: THanks for the suggestion I'll try it!

Comment: So I had:
Slicer teams = 
VAR selectedTeam= ALLSELECTED(Team[Team])
Return
FILTER(Team, Team[Team] IN selectedTeam)

And now I have:
Slicer teams = 
VAR selectedTeam= ALLSELECTED(Team[Team])
Return
FILTER(Team, Team[Team] IN selectedTeam)

Comment: the 2 expressions are exactly the same

Comment: sry I edited for too long...
Your suggestion worked like a Charm!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolves the issue.